# Geopandas gets creative when it can't find the street

Tags: python, geopandas, geopy

I have noticed an interesting behavior when when working with Geopandas.  When Geopandas is fed a street that it presumably cannot find, it will somehow substitute an existing street that seems to be near the city of the address.  See below input/output:

```
> getGeoLoc(["2502 asdfasdf St, Albany NY"])
  0    POINT (-73.78173 42.66155)
```

The above jibberish returned coordinate is 500 Hamilton St Apartment 1, Albany, NY

What's even more bizarre is that varying the street number results in additional locations around the returned street.  This doesn't apparently work if you botch the number, city or state, which returns a null value.

This makes things a little tricky when I'm bulk converting addresses because I can't really tell if it is actually finding the street or if I've fed it a bad piece of data.

Can anybody explain this or tell me how to get an error for a bad street name?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior in `geopandas` is due to the geocoding service. Those geocoding services (e.g., Google Maps API, OpenStreetMap Nominatim) convert addresses into geographic coordinates.

When you an address that cannot be found, the geocoding service attempts to perform approximate matching or infer a nearby location based on the available information. This can sometimes result in unexpected substitutions, where the geocoding service assigns coordinates to a similar-sounding or nearby street. As you point out, it gets creative.

You can however check the result of the geocoding operation and examine the quality or confidence of the returned coordinates. Most geocoding services provide a geocoding quality code or similar indicator that reflects the accuracy or reliability of the geocoded result.

My advice to you is to clean your data before you pass it to the geocoding service via geopandas. I recently had my tam spend two complete weeks doing this to be able to return accurate positions of thousands of stores....painful but necessary.

Comment: Yea, so many of my life's problems can be solved by data cleaning and I'm running some really dirty data here.  As a backstop, do you know how to get geopandas to return the confidence value?